# Getting a max column value based by another column value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column where the earliest first season of a head football coach in U.S. Division 1 college football for each conference is in it.

For example, all "longest tenure" column values for the American Conference will be "2007", while for the ACC, it will be "2008", and so on.

Once that gets resolved, how will I be able to pull that off in R? Is there a way it can be accomplished in the dplyr package?

```
School,Conference,Head coach,First season,Current W,Current L,Current W%,Career W,Career L,Career W%,Offensive coordinator(s),Defensive coordinator(s),Special Teams coordinator(s)
Cincinnati Bearcats,The American,Luke Fickell,2017,35,14,0.71399999999999997,41,21,0.66100000000000003,Mike Denbrock,Mike Tressel,Brian Mason
East Carolina Pirates,The American,Mike Houston,2019,7,14,0.33300000000000002,7,14,0.33300000000000002,Donnie Kirkpatrick,Blake Harrell,Tim Daoust
Houston Cougars,The American,Dana Holgorsen,2019,7,13,0.35,68,54,0.55700000000000005,Shannon Dawson,Doug Belk,Mark Scott
Memphis Tigers,The American,Ryan Silverfield,2020,8,4,0.66700000000000004,8,4,0.66700000000000004,Kevin Johns,Mike MacIntyre,Vacant
Navy Midshipmen,The American,Ken Niumatalolo,2007,101,67,0.60099999999999998,101,67,0.60099999999999998,Ivin Jasper,Brian Newberry,Danny O'Rourke
SMU Mustangs,The American,Sonny Dykes,2018,22,14,0.61099999999999999,63,59,0.51600000000000001,Garrett Riley,Jim Leavitt,Chris Brasfield
South Florida Bulls,The American,Jeff Scott,2020,1,8,0.111,1,8,0.111,Charlie Weis Jr.,Glenn Spencer,Daniel Da Prato
Temple Owls,The American,Rod Carey,2019,9,11,0.45,61,41,0.59799999999999998,Mike Uremovich,Jeff Knowles,Brett Diersen
Tulane Green Wave,The American,Willie Fritz,2016,29,33,0.46800000000000003,46,40,0.53500000000000003,Chip Long,Chris Hampton,Willie Fritz
Tulsa Golden Hurricane,The American,Philip Montgomery,2015,31,40,0.437,31,40,0.437,Philip Montgomery,Joseph Gillespie,Calvin Lowry
UCF Knights,The American,Gus Malzahn,2021,0,0,–,77,38,0.67,Tim Harris Jr. / G. J. Kinne,David Gibbs / Travis Williams,Brian Blackmon
Boston College Eagles,ACC,Jeff Hafley,2020,6,5,0.54500000000000004,6,5,0.54500000000000004,Frank Cignetti Jr.,Tem Lukabu,Matt Thurin
Clemson Tigers,ACC,Dabo Swinney,2008,140,33,0.80900000000000005,140,33,0.80900000000000005,Tony Elliott,Brent Venables,Mickey Conn
Duke Blue Devils,ACC,David Cutcliffe,2008,74,88,0.45700000000000002,118,117,0.502,Re'Quan Boyette / Jeff Faris,Ben Albert / Matt Guerrieri,Kirk Benedict
Florida State Seminoles,ACC,Mike Norvell,2020,3,6,0.33300000000000002,41,21,0.66100000000000003,Kenny Dillingham,Adam Fuller,John Papuchis
Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets,ACC,Geoff Collins,2019,6,16,0.27300000000000002,21,26,0.44700000000000001,Dave Patenaude,Nathan Burton / Andrew Thacker,Jeff Popovich / Chris Wiesehan
Louisville Cardinals,ACC,Scott Satterfield,2019,12,13,0.48,59,29,0.67,Vacant,Bryan Brown / Cort Dennison,Stu Holt
Miami Hurricanes,ACC,Manny Diaz,2019,14,10,0.58299999999999996,14,10,0.58299999999999996,Rhett Lashlee,Manny Diaz,Jonathan Patke
North Carolina Tar Heels,ACC,Mack Brown,2019[N 1],15,10,0.6,259,132,0.66200000000000003,Phil Longo,Jay Bateman / Tommy Thigpen,Jovan Dewitt
NC State Wolfpack,ACC,Dave Doeren,2013,55,46,0.54500000000000004,78,50,0.60899999999999999,Tim Beck,Tony Gibson,Todd Goebbel
Pittsburgh Panthers,ACC,Pat Narduzzi,2015,42,34,0.55300000000000005,42,34,0.55300000000000005,Mark Whipple,Randy Bates,Andre Powell
Syracuse Orange,ACC,Dino Babers,2016,24,36,0.4,42,45,0.48299999999999998,Sterlin Gilbert,Tony White,Vacant
Virginia Cavaliers,ACC,Bronco Mendenhall,2016,30,32,0.48399999999999999,129,75,0.63200000000000001,Robert Anae,Nick Howell / Kelly Poppinga,Ricky Brumfield
Virginia Tech Hokies,ACC,Justin Fuente,2016,38,26,0.59399999999999997,64,49,0.56599999999999995,Brad Cornelsen,Justin Hamilton,James Shibest
Wake Forest Demon Deacons,ACC,Dave Clawson,2014,40,45,0.47099999999999997,72,76,0.48599999999999999,Warren Ruggiero,Lyle Hemphill,Wayne Lineburg
Baylor Bears,Big 12,Dave Aranda,2020,2,7,0.222,2,7,0.222,Jeff Grimes,Ron Roberts,Matt Powledge
Iowa State Cyclones,Big 12,Matt Campbell,2016,35,28,0.55600000000000005,70,43,0.61899999999999999,Tom Manning,Jon Heacock,Vacant
Kansas Jayhawks,Big 12,Emmett Jones,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Mike DeBord,DJ Eliot,Jacob Schoonover
Kansas State Wildcats,Big 12,Chris Klieman,2019,12,11,0.52200000000000002,12,11,0.52200000000000002,Courtney Messingham,Joe Klanderman,Vacant
Oklahoma Sooners,Big 12,Lincoln Riley,2017,45,8,0.84899999999999998,45,8,0.84899999999999998,Bill Bedenbaugh / Cale Gundy,Alex Grinch,Joe Jon Finley
Oklahoma State Cowboys,Big 12,Mike Gundy,2005,137,67,0.67200000000000004,137,67,0.67200000000000004,Kasey Dunn,Jim Knowles,John Wozniak
TCU Horned Frogs,Big 12,Gary Patterson,2000,178,74,0.70599999999999996,178,74,0.70599999999999996,Doug Meacham,Chad Glasgow,Dan Sharp
Texas Longhorns,Big 12,Steve Sarkisian,2021,0,0,–,46,35,0.56799999999999995,Kyle Flood,Jeff Choate / Pete Kwiatkowski,Jeff Banks
Texas Tech Red Raiders,Big 12,Matt Wells,2019,8,14,0.36399999999999999,52,48,0.52,Sonny Cumbie,Keith Patterson,Mark Tommerdahl
West Virginia Mountaineers,Big 12,Neal Brown,2019,11,11,0.5,46,27,0.63,Gerad Parker,ShaDon Brown / Jordan Lesley,Jeff Koonz
Illinois Fighting Illini,Big Ten,Bret Bielema,2021,0,0,–,97,58,0.626,Tony Petersen,Ryan Walters,Ben Miller
Indiana Hoosiers,Big Ten,Tom Allen,2017,24,22,0.52200000000000002,24,22,0.52200000000000002,Grant Heard / Nick Sheridan,Charlton Warren,Kasey Teegardin
Iowa Hawkeyes,Big Ten,Kirk Ferentz,1999,168,106,0.61299999999999999,168,106,0.61299999999999999,Brian Ferentz,Phil Parker,LeVar Woods
Maryland Terrapins,Big Ten,Mike Locksley,2019,6,17,0.26100000000000001,8,43,0.157,Dan Enos,Brian Stewart / Brian Williams,Ron Zook
Michigan Wolverines,Big Ten,Jim Harbaugh,2015,49,22,0.69,78,43,0.64500000000000002,Josh Gattis / Sherrone Moore,Maurice Linguist / Mike Macdonald,Jay Harbaugh
Michigan State Spartans,Big Ten,Mel Tucker,2020,2,5,0.28599999999999998,7,12,0.36799999999999999,Jay Johnson,Scottie Hazelton,Ross Els
Minnesota Golden Gophers,Big Ten,P. J. Fleck,2017,26,19,0.57799999999999996,56,41,0.57699999999999996,Mike Sanford Jr. / Matt Simon,Joe Harasymiak / Joe Rossi,Rob Wenger
Nebraska Cornhuskers,Big Ten,Scott Frost,2018,12,20,0.375,31,27,0.53400000000000003,Matt Lubick,Erik Chinander,Vacant
Northwestern Wildcats,Big Ten,Pat Fitzgerald,2006,106,81,0.56699999999999995,106,81,0.56699999999999995,Mike Bajakian,Jim O'Neil,Jeff Genyk
Ohio State Buckeyes,Big Ten,Ryan Day,2019,23,2,0.92,23,2,0.92,Kevin Wilson,Kerry Coombs,Parker Fleming
Penn State Nittany Lions,Big Ten,James Franklin,2014,60,28,0.68200000000000005,84,43,0.66100000000000003,Mike Yurcich,Brent Pry / Anthony Poindexter,Joe Lorig
Purdue Boilermakers,Big Ten,Jeff Brohm,2017,19,25,0.432,48,35,0.57799999999999996,Brian Brohm / JaMarcus Shephard,Brad Lambert,Marty Biagi
Rutgers Scarlet Knights,Big Ten,Greg Schiano,2020[N 2],3,6,0.33300000000000002,71,73,0.49299999999999999,Sean Gleeson,Robb Smith,Adam Scheier
Wisconsin Badgers,Big Ten,Paul Chryst,2015,56,19,0.747,75,38,0.66400000000000003,Joe Rudolph,Jim Leonhard,Chris Haering
Charlotte 49ers,C-USA,Will Healy,2019,9,10,0.47399999999999998,9,10,0.47399999999999998,Mark Carney,Brandon Cooper / Marcus West,Max Thurmond
Florida Atlantic Owls,C-USA,Willie Taggart,2020,5,4,0.55600000000000005,61,66,0.48,Mike Johnson,Mike Stoops,Raymond Woodie
Florida International Panthers,C-USA,Butch Davis,2017,23,21,0.52300000000000002,86,64,0.57299999999999995,Andrew Breiner,Everett Withers,Casey Horny
Louisiana Tech Bulldogs,C-USA,Skip Holtz,2013,61,41,0.59799999999999998,115,89,0.56399999999999995,Joe Sloan,David Blackwell,Dennis Smith
Marshall Thundering Herd,C-USA,Charles Huff,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Tim Cramsey,Lance Guidry,Jeremy Springer
Middle Tennessee Blue Raiders,C-USA,Rick Stockstill,2006,94,92,0.505,94,92,0.505,Brent Dearmon,Scott Shafer,Mike Polly
North Texas Mean Green,C-USA,Seth Littrell,2016,31,31,0.5,31,31,0.5,Mike Bloesch / Tommy Mainord,Phil Bennett,Chris Petrilli
Old Dominion Monarchs,C-USA,Ricky Rahne,2020,0,0,–,0,0,–,Kirk Campbell,Blake Seiler,Kevin Smith
Rice Owls,C-USA,Mike Bloomgren,2018,7,23,0.23300000000000001,7,23,0.23300000000000001,Marques Tuiasosopo,Brian Smith,Vacant
Southern Miss Golden Eagles,C-USA,Will Hall,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Cayden Cochran,Austin Armstrong,Greg Meyer
UAB Blazers,C-USA,Bill Clark,2014[N 3],40,22,0.64500000000000002,40,22,0.64500000000000002,Bryant Vincent,David Reeves,Heath Thomas
UTEP Miners,C-USA,Dana Dimel,2018,5,27,0.156,35,66,0.34699999999999998,Dave Warner,Bradley Dale Peveto,Joe Robinson
UTSA Roadrunners,C-USA,Jeff Traylor,2020,7,5,0.58299999999999996,7,5,0.58299999999999996,Barry Lunney Jr.,Jess Loepp / Rod Wright,Tommy Perry
Western Kentucky Hilltoppers,C-USA,Tyson Helton,2019,14,11,0.56000000000000005,14,11,0.56000000000000005,Zach Kittley,Maurice Crum Jr.,Andy LaRussa
Army Black Knights,Independent,Jeff Monken,2014,49,39,0.55700000000000005,49,39,0.55700000000000005,Brent Davis,Nate Woody,Sean Saturnio
BYU Cougars,Independent,Kalani Sitake,2016,38,26,0.59399999999999997,38,26,0.59399999999999997,Aaron Roderick,Ilaisa Tuiaki,Ed Lamb
Liberty Flames,Independent,Hugh Freeze,2019,18,6,0.75,67,33,0.67,Kent Austin / Maurice Harris,Scott Symons,Tanner Burns
New Mexico State Aggies,Independent,Doug Martin,2013,22,64,0.25600000000000001,51,117,0.30399999999999999,Doug Martin,Frank Spaziani,Matt Christian / Ronnie Pentz
Notre Dame Fighting Irish,Independent,Brian Kelly,2010,81,38,0.68100000000000005,135,60,0.69199999999999995,Tommy Rees,Marcus Freeman,Brian Polian
UConn Huskies,Independent,Randy Edsall,2017[N 4],6,30,0.16700000000000001,98,127,0.436,Frank Giufre,Lou Spanos,Eddie Allen
UMass Minutemen,Independent,Walt Bell,2019,1,15,6.3E-2,1,15,6.3E-2,Angelo Mirando,Tommy Restivo,Luke Paschall
Akron Zips,MAC,Tom Arth,2019,1,17,5.6000000000000001E-2,1,17,5.6000000000000001E-2,Tommy Zagorski,Matt Feeney,Chris Hurd
Ball State Cardinals,MAC,Mike Neu,2016,22,34,0.39300000000000002,22,34,0.39300000000000002,Kevin Lynch,Tyler Stockton,Patrick Dougherty
Bowling Green Falcons,MAC,Scot Loeffler,2019,3,14,0.17599999999999999,3,14,0.17599999999999999,Terry Malone,Eric Lewis,Bob Ligashesky
Buffalo Bulls,MAC,Lance Leipold,2015,37,33,0.52900000000000003,37,33,0.52900000000000003,Andy Kotelnicki / Jim Zebrowski,Brian Borland,Taiwo Onatolu
Central Michigan Chippewas,MAC,Jim McElwain,2019,11,9,0.55000000000000004,55,37,0.59799999999999998,Kevin Barbay,Robb Akey,Keith Murphy
Eastern Michigan Eagles,MAC,Chris Creighton,2014,30,51,0.37,30,51,0.37,Chris Creighton,Neal Neathery,Jay Nunez
Kent State Golden Flashes,MAC,Sean Lewis,2018,12,17,0.41399999999999998,12,17,0.41399999999999998,Andrew Sowder,Tom Kaufman,Zac Barton
Miami RedHawks,MAC,Chuck Martin,2014,32,46,0.41,32,46,0.41,Eric Koehler,John Hauser / Spence Nowinsky,Doug Shearer
Northern Illinois Huskies,MAC,Thomas Hammock,2019,5,13,0.27800000000000002,5,13,0.27800000000000002,Eric Eidsness,Derrick Jackson,Dan Jackson / Aaron Wilkins
Ohio Bobcats,MAC,Frank Solich,2005,115,82,0.58399999999999996,173,101,0.63100000000000001,Tim Albin,Ron Collins / Pete Germano,Nate Faanes
Toledo Rockets,MAC,Jason Candle,2016,38,21,0.64400000000000002,38,21,0.64400000000000002,Mike Hallett / Robert Weiner,Vince Kehres / Craig Kuligowski,Ross Watson
Western Michigan Broncos,MAC,Tim Lester,2017,24,20,0.54500000000000004,24,20,0.54500000000000004,Vacant,Lou Esposito,David Denham / Joe Palcic
Air Force Falcons,Mountain West,Troy Calhoun,2007,102,72,0.58599999999999997,102,72,0.58599999999999997,Mike Thiessen,John Rudzinski,Tim Horton
Boise State Broncos,Mountain West,Andy Avalos,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Tim Plough,Spencer Danielson / Kane Ioane,Stacy Collins
Colorado State Rams,Mountain West,Steve Addazio,2020,1,3,0.25,58,58,0.5,Jon Budmayr,Chuck Heater,Vacant
Fresno State Bulldogs,Mountain West,Kalen DeBoer,2020,3,3,0.5,3,3,0.5,Ryan Grubb,William Inge,Eric Schmidt
Hawaiʻi Rainbow Warriors,Mountain West,Todd Graham,2020,5,4,0.55600000000000005,100,65,0.60599999999999998,Bo Graham,Victor Santa Cruz / Jacob Yoro,Dan Phillips
Nevada Wolf Pack,Mountain West,Jay Norvell,2017,25,22,0.53200000000000003,25,22,0.53200000000000003,Matt Mumme,Brian Ward,Thomas Sheffield
New Mexico Lobos,Mountain West,Danny Gonzales,2020,2,5,0.28599999999999998,2,5,0.28599999999999998,Drew Mehringer / Derek Warehime,Rocky Long,Jamie Christian
San Diego State Aztecs,Mountain West,Brady Hoke,2020,4,4,0.5,82,76,0.51900000000000002,Jeff Hecklinski,Kurt Mattix,Doug Deakin
San José State Spartans,Mountain West,Brent Brennan,2017,15,30,0.33300000000000002,15,30,0.33300000000000002,Kevin McGiven,Derrick Odum,Scott White
UNLV Rebels,Mountain West,Marcus Arroyo,2020,0,6,0,0,6,0,Glenn Thomas,Peter Hansen,Vacant
Utah State Aggies,Mountain West,Blake Anderson,2021,0,0,–,51,37,0.57999999999999996,Anthony Tucker,Ephraim Banda,Nick Paremski
Wyoming Cowboys,Mountain West,Craig Bohl,2014,38,44,0.46300000000000002,38,44,0.46300000000000002,Tim Polasek,Jay Sawvel,Shannon Moore
Arizona Wildcats,Pac-12,Jedd Fisch,2021,0,0,–,1,1,0.5,Brennan Carroll,Don Brown,Keith Dudzinski
Arizona State Sun Devils,Pac-12,Herm Edwards,2018,17,13,0.56699999999999995,17,13,0.56699999999999995,Zak Hill,Antonio Pierce,Shawn Slocum
California Golden Bears,Pac-12,Justin Wilcox,2017,21,21,0.5,21,21,0.5,Bill Musgrave,Peter Sirmon,Charlie Ragle
Colorado Buffaloes,Pac-12,Karl Dorrell,2020,4,2,0.66700000000000004,39,29,0.57399999999999995,Darrin Chiaverini,Chris Wilson,Vacant
Oregon Ducks,Pac-12,Mario Cristobal,2018,25,10,0.71399999999999997,52,57,0.47699999999999998,Joe Moorhead,Tim DeRuyter,Bobby Williams
Oregon State Beavers,Pac-12,Jonathan Smith,2018,9,22,0.28999999999999998,9,22,0.28999999999999998,Brian Lindgren,Tim Tibesar,Jake Cookus
Stanford Cardinal,Pac-12,David Shaw,2011,90,36,0.71399999999999997,90,36,0.71399999999999997,Tavita Pritchard,Lance Anderson,Pete Alamar
UCLA Bruins,Pac-12,Chip Kelly,2018,10,21,0.32300000000000001,56,28,0.66700000000000004,Justin Frye,Jerry Azzinaro,Derek Sage
USC Trojans,Pac-12,Clay Helton,2015,45,23,0.66200000000000003,45,23,0.66200000000000003,Graham Harrell,Todd Orlando,Sean Snyder
Utah Utes,Pac-12,Kyle Whittingham,2005,134,66,0.67,134,66,0.67,Andy Ludwig,Morgan Scalley,Sharrieff Shah
Washington Huskies,Pac-12,Jimmy Lake,2020,3,1,0.75,3,1,0.75,John Donovan,Bob Gregory / Ikaika Malloe,Keith Bhonapha
Washington State Cougars,Pac-12,Nick Rolovich,2020,1,3,0.25,29,29,0.5,Brian Smith / Craig Stutzmann,Jake Dickert,Kyle Krantz
Alabama Crimson Tide,SEC,Nick Saban,2007,164,23,0.877,255,65,0.79700000000000004,Bill O'Brien,Pete Golding,Drew Svoboda
Arkansas Razorbacks,SEC,Sam Pittman,2020,3,7,0.3,3,7,0.3,Kendal Briles,Barry Odom,Scott Fountain
Auburn Tigers,SEC,Bryan Harsin,2021,0,0,–,76,24,0.76,Mike Bobo,Derek Mason,Bert Watts
Florida Gators,SEC,Dan Mullen,2018,29,9,0.76300000000000001,98,55,0.64100000000000001,Vacant,Todd Grantham,Greg Knox
Georgia Bulldogs,SEC,Kirby Smart,2016,52,13,0.8,52,13,0.8,Todd Monken,Dan Lanning / Glenn Schumann,Scott Cochran
Kentucky Wildcats,SEC,Mark Stoops,2013,49,50,0.495,49,50,0.495,Liam Coen,Brad White,Louie Matsakis
LSU Tigers,SEC,Ed Orgeron,2016,45,14,0.76300000000000001,62,41,0.60199999999999998,Jake Peetz,Daronte Jones,Greg McMahon
Ole Miss Rebels,SEC,Lane Kiffin,2020,5,5,0.5,66,39,0.629,Jeff Lebby,D. J. Durkin / Chris Partridge,Coleman Hutzler
Mississippi State Bulldogs,SEC,Mike Leach,2020,4,7,0.36399999999999999,143,97,0.59599999999999997,Mike Leach,Zach Arnett,Matt Brock
Missouri Tigers,SEC,Eliah Drinkwitz,2020,5,5,0.5,17,6,0.73899999999999999,Eliah Drinkwitz / Curtis Luper,Steve Wilks,Erik Link
South Carolina Gamecocks,SEC,Shane Beamer,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Marcus Satterfield,Clayton White,Pete Lembo
Tennessee Volunteers,SEC,Josh Heupel,2021,0,0,–,28,8,0.77800000000000002,Alex Golesh,Tim Banks,Mike Ekeler
Texas A&M Aggies,SEC,Jimbo Fisher,2018,26,10,0.72199999999999998,109,33,0.76800000000000002,Darrell Dickey,Mike Elko,Vacant
Vanderbilt Commodores,SEC,Clark Lea,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,David Raih,Jesse Minter,Justin Lustig
Appalachian State Mountaineers,Sun Belt,Shawn Clark,2020,10,3,0.76900000000000002,10,3,0.76900000000000002,Frank Ponce,Dale Jones,Brian Haines
Arkansas State Red Wolves,Sun Belt,Butch Jones,2021,0,0,–,84,54,0.60899999999999999,Keith Heckendorf,Rob Harley,Steve Hauser
Coastal Carolina Chanticleers,Sun Belt,Jamey Chadwell,2019,19,17,0.52800000000000002,19,17,0.52800000000000002,Newland Isaac / Willy Korn,Chad Staggs,Curt Baldus
Georgia Southern Eagles,Sun Belt,Chad Lunsford,2018,27,18,0.6,27,18,0.6,Doug Ruse,Scot Sloan,Joe Graves
Georgia State Panthers,Sun Belt,Shawn Elliott,2017,22,25,0.46800000000000003,23,30,0.434,Brad Glenn,Nick Fuqua,Shiel Wood
Louisiana Ragin' Cajuns,Sun Belt,Billy Napier,2018,28,11,0.71799999999999997,28,11,0.71799999999999997,Michael Desormeaux / Tim Leger,Patrick Toney,Chris Couch
Louisiana-Monroe Warhawks,Sun Belt,Terry Bowden,2021,0,0,–,82,69,0.54300000000000004,Rich Rodriguez,Zac Alley,Ron West
South Alabama Jaguars,Sun Belt,Kane Wommack,2021,0,0,–,0,0,–,Major Applewhite,Corey Batoon,Jamael Lett
Texas State Bobcats,Sun Belt,Jake Spavital,2019,5,19,0.20799999999999999,5,19,0.20799999999999999,Jacob Peeler,Brian Gambel / Zac Spavital,Nick Whitworth
Troy Trojans,Sun Belt,Chip Lindsey,2019,10,13,0.435,10,13,0.435,Luke Meadows,Brandon Hall,Dayne Brown
```

Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the dataframe from? Could you `dput()` the data?

Comment: Apologies, this was an excel copy from the following weblink: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_NCAA_Division_I_FBS_football_coaches

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Providing the link to the data is also inappropriate. You should post the ACTUAL DATA using dput()

Comment: I would like to think I made the changes. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this after importing your dataframe (using read_csv) would be to apply the minimum function to the years in the first season column.

`dplyr::mutate` is a function that allows for grouped data to be input and so we can find the earliest year in this column for each group of conferences.

As suggested in the comments a `dput(df)` function would be the best way to store the data. I have provided the ouput for the first 6 rows below in my reprex.

Additionally it is worth noting that when importing your data using read_csv the first season column was originally read in as a char column and so you may need to convert it to an double or integer set of values. I would do this using

```r
df$`First season` <- df$`First season` %>% as.integer()
```

My solution would be as follows for this dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(School = c("Cincinnati Bearcats", "East Carolina Pirates", 
                          "Houston Cougars", "Memphis Tigers", "Navy Midshipmen", "SMU Mustangs"),
                     Conference = c("The American", "The American", "The American",
                                    "The American", "The American", "The American"),
                     `Head coach` = c("Luke Fickell", "Mike Houston", "Dana Holgorsen",
                                      "Ryan Silverfield", "Ken Niumatalolo", "Sonny Dykes"),
                     `First season` = c(2017, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2007, 2018), 
                     `Current W` = c(35, 7, 7, 8, 101, 22),
                     `Current L` = c(14, 14, 13, 4, 67, 14),
                     `Current W%` = c("0.71399999999999997", "0.33300000000000002", "0.35", "0.66700000000000004", "0.60099999999999998", "0.61099999999999999"),
                     `Career W` = c(41, 7, 68, 8, 101, 63),
                     `Career L` = c(21, 14, 54, 4, 67, 59),
                     `Career W%` = c("0.66100000000000003", "0.33300000000000002", "0.55700000000000005", "0.66700000000000004", "0.60099999999999998", "0.51600000000000001"), 
                     `Offensive coordinator(s)` = c("Mike Denbrock", "Donnie Kirkpatrick", "Shannon Dawson", "Kevin Johns", "Ivin Jasper", "Garrett Riley"),
                     `Defensive coordinator(s)` = c("Mike Tressel",  "Blake Harrell", "Doug Belk", "Mike MacIntyre", "Brian Newberry", "Jim Leavitt"),
                     `Special Teams coordinator(s)` = c("Brian Mason", "Tim Daoust", "Mark Scott", "Vacant", "Danny O'Rourke", "Chris Brasfield")),
                      row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df$`First season` <- df$`First season` %>% as.integer()

df %>% 
  group_by(Conference) %>% 
  mutate(EarliestStartingTenure = min(`First season`, na.rm))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 14
#> # Groups:   Conference [1]
#>   School        Conference  `Head coach`  `First season` `Current W` `Current L`
#>   <chr>         <chr>       <chr>                  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 Cincinnati B~ The Americ~ Luke Fickell            2017          35          14
#> 2 East Carolin~ The Americ~ Mike Houston            2019           7          14
#> 3 Houston Coug~ The Americ~ Dana Holgors~           2019           7          13
#> 4 Memphis Tige~ The Americ~ Ryan Silverf~           2020           8           4
#> 5 Navy Midship~ The Americ~ Ken Niumatal~           2007         101          67
#> 6 SMU Mustangs  The Americ~ Sonny Dykes             2018          22          14
#> # ... with 8 more variables: Current W% <chr>, Career W <dbl>, Career L <dbl>,
#> #   Career W% <chr>, Offensive coordinator(s) <chr>,
#> #   Defensive coordinator(s) <chr>, Special Teams coordinator(s) <chr>,
#> #   EarliestStartingTenure <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>